# Требуется распаковать string

Tags: delphi, zip

Есть строка `#$1F'‹'#8#0#0#0#0#0#0#0'«V*ИМKWІ245І0¶0337·ґ0'#$00AD#5#0'4=;Ґ'#$16#0#0#0`, которая приходит в компоненту websocket от ipworks. В документации к api сервиса написано, что нужно ее распаковать.

> All return data of websocket APIs needs to unzip

На просторах интернета нашел вот такой код:

```
function Unzip(const zipped: string): string;
var
  strInput,
  strOutput: TStringStream;
  Unzipper: TZDecompressionStream;
begin
  Result:= '';
  strInput:= TStringStream.Create(zipped);
  strOutput:= TStringStream.Create;
  try
    Unzipper:= TZDecompressionStream.Create(strInput);
    try
      strOutput.CopyFrom(Unzipper, Unzipper.Size);
    finally
      Unzipper.Free;
    end;
    Result:= strOutput.DataString;
  finally
    strInput.Free;
    strOutput.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Но на строчке strOutput.CopyFrom - появляется ошибка "data error". 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно распаковать эту строчку.

Comment: Попробуйте так: `strOutput.CopyFrom(Unzipper, 0);`

Comment: Та же ошибка. Пробую сразу после создания Unzipper получить его размер, но выдает ошибку `Delphi exception EZDecompressionError at $41BFF8B1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос решился изменением значения `WindowBits` при создании класса `TZDecompressionStream`.
Теперь функция выглядит вот так:

```
function Unzip(const zipped: string): string;
var
  strInput,
  strOutput: TStringStream;
  Unzipper: TZDecompressionStream;
begin
  Result:= '';
  strInput:= TStringStream.Create(zipped);

  strOutput:= TStringStream.Create;
  try
    Unzipper:= TZDecompressionStream.Create(strInput, 31);
    try
      strOutput.CopyFrom(Unzipper, 0);//Unzipper.Size);
    finally
      FreeAndNil(Unzipper);
    end;
    Result:= strOutput.DataString;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(strInput);
    FreeAndNil(strOutput);
  end;
end;
```